# Different types of catplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I was going though some tutorials on seaborn. I am confused on how different types of plots are coded.
For instance what is a difference between sns.catplot( kind = 'bar') VS sns.barplot. Aren't these two same. Why one prefer to do sns.catplot(kind = 'bar') over sns.barplot.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how `catplot` is coded here: [implementation of catplot](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/categorical.py#L3668-L3757).

`catplot` is a wrapper of `barplot` and others.

Here is the documentation of `catplot`:

> **Figure-level interface** for drawing categorical plots onto a FacetGrid.
>
> This function **provides access to** several **axes-level functions** that show the relationship between a numerical and one or more categorical variables using one of several visual representations. The kind parameter selects the underlying axes-level function to use

It offers thus a convenient way to plot multiple `barplot` (for instance) on a `FacedGrid`.